# I cannot solve this simple exercise in Deitel Visual C# 2010

Tags: c#, arrays

I've been studying Deitel's Visual C# 2010. I'm stuck at an exercise in the chapter about arrays. It's been bugging me for days now, and I've written the code several times now and each times something goes wrong.

The exercise is asking to develop a new reservation system for a small airline company. The capacity of an airplane is 10 seats. So you ask the customer to input 1 for First Class and 2 for Economy. Seats from 1 to 5 are for first class. Seats from 6 to 10 are for economy.

I must use a one-dimensional array of type bool to represent the seating char of the plane. Initialize all elements of the array to false to represent vacant seats (Luckily bool initializes to false anyway, because I do not know how to initialize an array). As each seat is assigned, set the corresponding element in the plane to true.

The app should never assign a seat that's already been seated. When the economy class is full, the app should ask the customer if he wants to fly in first class (and vice versa). If the customer responds with yes, assign him in the economy class (if there's an empty seat there). If there is no empty seats in economy or the customer refuses to fly in first class, then just display to him that "The next flight is after three hours!).

I'm self-studying the book. This is not an assignment or homework. I really do not wish to post the code I've written because I want a completely fresh way to solve the problem, but I'm pretty sure that I will be asked about the code, so here it is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Craps_Game
{
    class AirlineReservation
    {
        private static bool[] seats = new bool[10];


    private static void FirstClass(ref bool[] seats)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            if (seats[i] == false)
            {
                seats[i] = true;
                Console.WriteLine("Your seat number is " + i);
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("First Class is full. Would you like to fly Economy?");
                if (Console.ReadLine().ToLower() == "y")
                    Economy(ref seats);
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("The next flight is in three hours!. Good bye");
            }
        }
    }


    private static void Economy(ref bool[] seats)
    {
        for (int i = 5; i < 10; i++)
            if (seats[i] == false)
                seats[i] = true;
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Economy class is full. Would you like to fly First Class");
                if (Console.ReadLine().ToLower() == "y")
                    FirstClass(ref seats);
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("The next flight is in three hours!. Good Bye");
            }

    }


    public static void Reservation()
    {
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter 1 to fly First Class");
            Console.WriteLine("Enter 2 to fly Economy Class");
            if (Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()) == 1)
                FirstClass(ref seats);
            else
                Economy(ref seats);
        } while (true);
    }
}
```

}

Bear in mind that I would prefer a completely different way of solving the problem, instead of fixing this one :)

Comment: There are a multitude of problem with this code. Recommendation: Learn how to use the debugger. Learn how to step through your code one line at a time and inspect the contents of variables and your array. I did this with your code, and the loop that sets the first seat as taken checks `seats[0]` the first time through, sees that it's open, and assigns it. The second time through, it checks `seats[0]`, sees that it's occupied, and then executes the else part of the conditional even though four seats are free. It's terribly obvious when you step line-by-line that it's not doing what you want.

Comment: See this MSDN page for an introduction: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173083(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: @Steve I know that. I did step through it with a breakpoint and I do know that's the problem with. But I still cannot fix it This one is just the latest attempt.

Comment: You're making a mistake I often see beginners make; everything is `static`. This is almost always the wrong thing to do; make a `new AirlineReservation` in your controlling class and call `Reservation` or whatever from that. You do not need to pass `ref seatc` to your class methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"I must use a one-dimensional array of type bool to represent the seating char of the plane"

"I want a completely fresh way to solve the problem"

"Bear in mind that I would prefer a completely different way of solving the problem, instead of fixing this one"

So be it! Others have given you really good advice already, but here's "fresh" way to do it.

```
using System;

namespace FunnyConsoleApplication
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Airplane plane = new Airplane();
            bool reserve = true;

            while (reserve)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Enter [1] to fly First Class ({0} vacant)", plane.VacantFirstClassSeats());
                Console.WriteLine("Enter [2] to fly Economy Class ({0} vacant)", plane.VacantEconomySeats());

                string input = Console.ReadLine();

                switch (input)
                {
                    case "1":
                        if (plane.HasFirstClassSeats)
                        {
                            plane.ReserveFirstClassSeat();
                        }
                        else if (plane.HasEconomySeats)
                        {
                            if (IsOk("No vacancy, enter [y] to fly Economy instead?"))
                                plane.ReserveEconomySeat();
                            else
                                reserve = false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            reserve = false;
                        }
                        break;

                    case "2":
                        if (plane.HasEconomySeats)
                        {
                            plane.ReserveEconomySeat();
                        }
                        else if (plane.HasFirstClassSeats)
                        {
                            if (IsOk("No vacancy, enter [y] to fly First Class instead?"))
                                plane.ReserveFirstClassSeat();
                            else
                                reserve = false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            reserve = false;
                        }
                        break;
                }

                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("No can do, good bye!");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static bool IsOk(string question)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(question);
            return string.Compare(Console.ReadLine(), "y", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0;
        }
    }

    public class Airplane
    {
        private readonly bool[] _seats = new bool[10];

        public bool HasFirstClassSeats
        {
            get { return HasSeats(0); }
        }

        public bool HasEconomySeats
        {
            get { return HasSeats(5); }
        }

        public int VacantFirstClassSeats()
        {
            return GetVacant(0);
        }

        public int VacantEconomySeats()
        {
            return GetVacant(5);
        }

        public void ReserveFirstClassSeat()
        {
            Reserve(0);
        }

        public void ReserveEconomySeat()
        {
            Reserve(5);
        }

        private bool HasSeats(int index)
        {
            for (int i = index; i < index + 5; i++)
            {
                if (!_seats[i])
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        private int GetVacant(int index)
        {
            int count = 0;
            for (int i = index; i < index + 5; i++)
            {
                if (!_seats[i])
                    count++;
            }
            return count;
        }

        private void Reserve(int index)
        {
            for (int i = index; i < index + 5; i++)
            {
                if (!_seats[i])
                {
                    _seats[i] = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which gives you

[image: funnyconsoleapp]

Answer (score 4):

I don't want to solve the entire problem in code since you are learning, but I will show you the major things I saw in your code that is a bug.

- Your `Economy` method was not exiting the loop if it found that a
  seat was available. It needed to break.
- Your `else` when you did not find a seat was not checking if all of the seats were taken. Checking if `i == 9` will make it so it will only go to `FirstClass` if there are no more seats, not before.

```
private static void Economy(ref bool[] seats)
{
    for (int i = 5; i < 10; i++)
    {   // <---- Added the brackets
        if (seats[i] == false)
        {
            seats[i] = true;
            break;  // <----- You forgot to break when you reserved a seat.
        }
        else if (i == 9)  // <---- You weren't checking if all seats are taken.
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Economy class is full. Would you like to fly First Class");
            if (Console.ReadLine().ToLower() == "y")
                FirstClass(ref seats);
            else
                Console.WriteLine("The next flight is in three hours!. Good Bye");
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Also, it's possible, if all seats are taken (and if the code worked enough to get this far), that the user could get in a loop of questions - "First class is full, economy?" followed by "Economy class is full, first class?", and back and forth until the user gives up.

Comment: @Steve Yes, I had a piece written out about changing his methods to return bool in order to determine if a seat was reserved, but thought maybe that would be something he could learn once he got it up and running.

Comment: @TyCobb The idea of a method that checks if the seats are filled did cross my mind :). But I failed at that as well. This problem has frustrated me to no end. After I spent a fair amount reading and studying OOP concepts, It's humbling and annoying to realize you still suck at the basics :).

Comment: @mustafa I would almost recommend not learning OOP quite yet. You're struggling with basic conditionals and loops. Learn those first.

Comment: @Steve I've actually finished a university course on OOP in C++ :). The class was not heavy on coding and focused on the concepts of OOP and I've understood them quite well. But you're right. It seems that I need to focus again on the basics.

Answer (score 3):

I like the way you approach programming and your task and this site!

Therefore I would hate to write out the code for you - all the fun is getting it done by yourself. But since you are stuck let me give you a few hints:

- Starting at the bottom, the first thing that comes to mind is that you are always offering both classes even when one or both are full. Here is a function header that could help to break things down even further than you already have done:

> ```
> public int getFirstVacantSeatIn(int classType)
> // returns 1-5 for classType=1, 6-10 for classType=2, -1 if classType is full
> ```

You can use this function to make the prompt dynamic like this:

```
Console.WriteLine( ( getFirstVacantSeatIn(1) >= 0 ?  
                     "Enter 1 to fly First Class") : "First Class is full");
```

And you can reuse it when you try to assign the new seats..:

- Another point is that you offer switching between classes when one is full without checking if the other one actually isn't full, too. I suspect that is the problem you are facing?

So you should check before offering to up- or downgrade.. The above function will help here as well. If you can **re-use** something, chances are that it was right to create that thing..

The secret is ever so often to **break your problem down further and further** until it goes away, always using/creating **useful names** for the sub-problems..

Comment: I highly suggest renaming `class` parameter to something else or at least doing `@class` ;)

Comment: OK, agreed ;-) (I'm so easy to convince..)